# Best way to split large media files for sharing

Tags: video, file-sharing, file-transfer

I have a large `.mkv` file that I am looking to share with a friend. My Dropbox limit is 2GB so I am looking for a simple way to split the file in to chunks of say 1gb, send them individually and the have him recompile it on his end.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than going to the effort of splitting it then re-combining at the other end...

There are dozens of file-sending sites - I mean direct user-to-user not *'dodgy stuff off the interwebz'*. I've used https://www.wetransfer.com before now, but Google has a whole lot more options under 'send large files free'

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is just split the video in half using iMovie or Final Cut Pro X, then export the project and then send it. Just have your recipient put both halves back together again using iMovie or FCPX.

Comment: You can split a video in QuickTime using `CMD+T`, too

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should go through the hassle of splitting your file. I'll go ahead and quote [my own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209238/83064) from a previous post: P2P transfer using torrent.

In your situation, here are the **benefits**:

- At least as fast as other internet transfers: your upload speed will determine the transfer speed
- No need to wait for an initial upload to start the download on the other side
- No extra local/cloud storage space needed
- No size limit (well, almost)
- The file can be played during file transfer

Of course, there are a few **drawbacks**, too:

- You'll need torrent software on both machines
- The connection between your two machines can take a while